# How should I fill out part 33 of the Schengen visa application form if I have several sponsors?

Tags: visas, applications, schengen-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I want to visit France, but I am a student. My parents sponsor my expenses throughout the journey. I also have an invitation letter from an EU citizen, who is my cousin. She provides me accommodation during this trip. In that case, what should I fill in section 33 of the [visa form](http://www.esteri.it/mae/servizi/stranieri/formulario_visto_schengen_en.pdf)?

> 33. Cost of travelling and living during the applicant's stay is covered: ...

Comment: Where are you from?

Comment: dhaka,bangladesh

Answer (score 1):

Provide the information about your EU-citizen cousin in response to question 31:

> **Surname and first name of the inviting person(s) in the Member State(s)**. If not applicable, name of hotel(s) or temporary accommodation(s) in the Member State(s)
>
> **Address and e-mail address of inviting person(s)**/hotel(s)/temporary accommodation(s)

Use section 33 to indicate how your parents are providing financial support: 
☒ by a sponsor 
☒ other (fill in your parent's information
and then tick the means of support, as it applies (one or more box).

[image]